# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'exit' (T_EXIT) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Chat\Chat\includes\signup.inc.php on line 12

Tags: php

trying to make a sign up page but when someone signs in an error comes, why? line(s): 12.

```
if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($passwordrepeat)) {
header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfeilds&".$username)
exit(); // <-- Here!
```

Comment: you need to add `semicolon` after `header` line `header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfeilds&".$username);`

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this -**

```
// You should add ';' after header function

if (empty($username) || empty($password) || empty($passwordrepeat)) {
header("Location: ../signup.php?error=emptyfeilds&".$username);
exit(); // <-- Here!
}
```

Comment: 12 but line 13 is wrong

Comment: actually, you forget to close your if statment  curly braces , i also closed the curly braces in the code just check that